# externalize angular component

Tags: angular, components, runtime, store

I would like to extract a component from my angular application 'A' then stock it beside to re-load it in another angular application 'B' with the same node_modules and run it, so am looking to make like Angular component designer

Comment: what is the question? I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. This just seems way too little information to receive a precise answer

Comment: What? What? What? A component by definition can be reused whenever you want

Comment: That's not how Angular works. Are you wanting to build standalone components that are built using Angular, but can be used in other applications? If so, have a look at Angular Elements, but your mileage may vary: https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: am looking to make an engin which can help to generate angular components and run it as independent angular app. so I want just to make it easy to build custom angular app.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically parse expressions in AngularJS but not in Angular2+. It's impossible to do it dynamically. Only way is to load "pure HTML" from database (without any bindings).